# SIGSEGV when using sql after upgrading Go from 1.15.15 to 1.21.3

Tags: linux, sqlite, go, segmentation-fault, cgo

I'm sorry for uncertain question,
but maybe someone has an answer or can provide some advice
after taking a look at callstack?

After upgrading Go from 1.15.15 to 1.21.3,
app crashes after run.

> GCC version: 4.6.0
> Linux kernel version: 2.6.33

Call stack:

```bash
Linux26[mmm]::/path_to_go/src/my_app(0)> ./my_app
... log omission ...
SIGSEGV: segmentation violation
PC=0x874c7c9 m=0 sigcode=1
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x86c4ca0, 0xa22951c)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x61 fp=0xa229508 sp=0xa2294f0 pc=0x806f961
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3._Cfunc__sqlite3_step_row_internal(0x9f580a8, 0xa2a6730, 0xa2a6738)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:378 +0x3b fp=0xa22951c sp=0xa229508 pc=0x83de6fb
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).execSync.func3(0xa29bf00, 0xa2a6730, 0xa2a6738)
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.13/sqlite3.go:2082 +0x62 fp=0xa229534 sp=0xa22951c pc=0x83f0462
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).execSync(0xa29bf00, {0x90ba9a0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.13/sqlite3.go:2082 +0x8d fp=0xa229564 sp=0xa229534 pc=0x83f01fd
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).exec(0xa29bf00, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0x90ba9a0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.13/sqlite3.go:2044 +0x34b fp=0xa229604 sp=0xa229564 pc=0x83f001b
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteConn).exec(0xa28fa70, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x90ba9a0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.13/sqlite3.go:875 +0x24d fp=0xa2296bc sp=0xa229604 pc=0x83e773d
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteConn).ExecContext(0xa28fa70, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x90ba9a0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.13/sqlite3_go18.go:41 +0xe7 fp=0xa229714 sp=0xa2296bc pc=0x83ddc27
database/sql.ctxDriverExec({0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0xeceaf150, 0xa28fa70}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x90ba9a0, 0x0, ...})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/ctxutil.go:31 +0x8f fp=0xa229768 sp=0xa229714 pc=0x83cde6f
database/sql.(*DB).execDC.func2()
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1675 +0x150 fp=0xa2297d4 sp=0xa229768 pc=0x83d4c40
database/sql.withLock({0x8a1c824, 0xa27ce40}, 0xa2298a8)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3502 +0x84 fp=0xa2297f0 sp=0xa2297d4 pc=0x83dc224
database/sql.(*DB).execDC(0xa1b97a0, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, 0xa27ce40, 0xa22992c, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1670 +0x24c fp=0xa2298f4 sp=0xa2297f0 pc=0x83d46cc
database/sql.(*DB).exec(0xa1b97a0, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1655 +0xdc fp=0xa229938 sp=0xa2298f4 pc=0x83d444c
database/sql.(*DB).ExecContext.func1(0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1634 +0x7c fp=0xa229980 sp=0xa229938 pc=0x83d426c
database/sql.(*DB).retry(0xa1b97a0, 0xa2299c8)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1538 +0x5f fp=0xa2299a8 sp=0xa229980 pc=0x83d395f
database/sql.(*DB).ExecContext(0xa1b97a0, {0x8a1de2c, 0x90ba9a0}, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1633 +0xae fp=0xa2299f8 sp=0xa2299a8 pc=0x83d41ae
database/sql.(*DB).Exec(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1647
web/acsr/resource.(*DbmsDb).Exec(0xa29cc88, {0xa2dc200, 0x1fd}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/acsr/resource/dbms.go:96 +0x63 fp=0xa229a34 sp=0xa2299f8 pc=0x841fce3
web/controller.(*AController).createMyDatabase(0xa27cd20)
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/controller/a_controller.go:154 +0x349 fp=0xa229aa4 sp=0xa229a34 pc=0x84a4bd9
web/controller.(*AController).Initialize(0xa27cd20)
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/controller/a_controller.go:96 +0x25 fp=0xa229abc sp=0xa229aa4 pc=0x84a46e5
web/controller.Controllers.Initialize({0xa27cde0, 0xc, 0xc})
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/controller/controllers.go:42 +0x40 fp=0xa229ad0 sp=0xa229abc pc=0x84aa370
main.Initialize.func1({0xa27cde0, 0xc, 0xc})
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/main.go:218 +0x38 fp=0xa229aec sp=0xa229ad0 pc=0x86c0788
runtime.call16(0xa29b940, 0xa29c488, 0xa2ae2c0, 0xc, 0xc, 0xc, 0xa229b6c)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:544 +0x30 fp=0xa229b00 sp=0xa229aec pc=0x80dcc50
reflect.Value.call({0x884df80, 0xa29c488, 0x13}, {0x892da21, 0x4}, {0xa19bb60, 0x1, 0x1})
        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:596 +0xa15 fp=0xa229db0 sp=0xa229b00 pc=0x8111435
reflect.Value.Call({0x884df80, 0xa29c488, 0x13}, {0xa19bb60, 0x1, 0x1})
        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:380 +0x7f fp=0xa229dec sp=0xa229db0 pc=0x811087f
go.uber.org/dig.defaultInvoker({0x884df80, 0xa29c488, 0x13}, {0xa19bb60, 0x1, 0x1})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/dig@v1.10.0/dig.go:284 +0x49 fp=0xa229e14 sp=0xa229dec pc=0x84f4e89
go.uber.org/dig.(*Container).Invoke(0xa1bfdd0, {0x884df80, 0xa29c488}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/go.uber.org/dig@v1.10.0/dig.go:439 +0x2b3 fp=0xa229ed0 sp=0xa229e14 pc=0x84f5bd3
main.Initialize(0xa1bfdd0)
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/main.go:217 +0xbc fp=0xa229ef8 sp=0xa229ed0 pc=0x86c072c
main.main()
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/main.go:83 +0xb55 fp=0xa229fa4 sp=0xa229ef8 pc=0x86c01a5
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267 +0x2dd fp=0xa229ff0 sp=0xa229fa4 pc=0x80a9c4d
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa229ff4 sp=0xa229ff0 pc=0x80dde51

goroutine 2 [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x89699ac, 0x8eb5aa8, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa05afdc sp=0xa05afc8 pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.forcegchelper()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:322 +0xd3 fp=0xa05aff0 sp=0xa05afdc pc=0x80a9f43
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa05aff4 sp=0xa05aff0 pc=0x80dde51
created by runtime.init.5 in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:310 +0x23

goroutine 3 [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x89699ac, 0x8eb64b0, 0xc, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa05b7cc sp=0xa05b7b8 pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.bgsweep(0xa032500)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:280 +0x9b fp=0xa05b7e8 sp=0xa05b7cc pc=0x809291b
runtime.gcenable.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x27 fp=0xa05b7f0 sp=0xa05b7e8 pc=0x8084717
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa05b7f4 sp=0xa05b7f0 pc=0x80dde51
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x77

goroutine 4 [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x89699ac, 0x8eb68c0, 0xd, 0x14, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa05bfb8 sp=0xa05bfa4 pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x8eb68c0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x60 fp=0xa05bfcc sp=0xa05bfb8 pc=0x808fc70
runtime.bgscavenge(0xa032500)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x4b fp=0xa05bfe8 sp=0xa05bfcc pc=0x80902eb
runtime.gcenable.func2()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0x27 fp=0xa05bff0 sp=0xa05bfe8 pc=0x80846d7
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa05bff4 sp=0xa05bff0 pc=0x80dde51
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0xb7

goroutine 18 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x8969844, 0x90baa18, 0x10, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa05a798 sp=0xa05a784 pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.runfinq()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:193 +0xfc fp=0xa05a7f0 sp=0xa05a798 pc=0x808385c
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa05a7f4 sp=0xa05a7f0 pc=0x80dde51
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:163 +0x60

goroutine 19 [chan receive]:
runtime.gopark(0x8969824, 0xa18ebf0, 0xe, 0x17, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa06df80 sp=0xa06df6c pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.chanrecv(0xa18ebc0, 0xa06dfdf, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/chan.go:583 +0x3b1 fp=0xa06dfbc sp=0xa06df80 pc=0x80719e1
runtime.chanrecv2(0xa18ebc0, 0xa06dfdf)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/chan.go:447 +0x1c fp=0xa06dfd0 sp=0xa06dfbc pc=0x807161c
gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack%2ev2.(*Logger).millRun(0xa286c40)
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2@v2.0.0/lumberjack.go:379 +0x47 fp=0xa06dfe8 sp=0xa06dfd0 pc=0x869be87
gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack%2ev2.(*Logger).mill.func1.1()
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2@v2.0.0/lumberjack.go:390 +0x27 fp=0xa06dff0 sp=0xa06dfe8 pc=0x869bff7
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa06dff4 sp=0xa06dff0 pc=0x80dde51
created by gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack%2ev2.(*Logger).mill.func1 in goroutine 1
        /path_to_go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2@v2.0.0/lumberjack.go:390 +0x9a

goroutine 20 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x86c1590, 0xa056fa0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x61 fp=0xa056f8c sp=0xa056f74 pc=0x806f961
web/acsr/pcc._Cfunc_QcRecv(0x2240000, 0xa100020, 0x0, 0x0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:745 +0x3f fp=0xa056fa0 sp=0xa056f8c pc=0x83bdccf
web/acsr/pcc.(*Qc).Recv.func1(0x2240000, 0xa100020)
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/acsr/pcc/qc_linux.go:102 +0x6b fp=0xa056fb8 sp=0xa056fa0 pc=0x83bffeb
web/acsr/pcc.(*Qc).Recv(0x90ba9a0, 0x2240000, 0xa046058)
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/acsr/pcc/qc_linux.go:102 +0x37 fp=0xa056fcc sp=0xa056fb8 pc=0x83bff47
web/controller.(*EventHelper).Initialize.func1()
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/controller/event_helper.go:55 +0x7f fp=0xa056ff0 sp=0xa056fcc pc=0x84aafcf
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa056ff4 sp=0xa056ff0 pc=0x80dde51
created by web/controller.(*EventHelper).Initialize in goroutine 1
        /path_to_go/src/my_app/controller/event_helper.go:53 +0xef

goroutine 21 [select]:
runtime.gopark(0x89699e0, 0x0, 0x9, 0x18, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa0576c4 sp=0xa0576b0 pc=0x80aa11c
runtime.selectgo(0xa0577cc, 0xa0577c4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:327 +0xaca fp=0xa0577a4 sp=0xa0576c4 pc=0x80bb93a
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xa1b97a0, {0x8a1decc, 0xa28f710})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1218 +0xab fp=0xa0577e0 sp=0xa0577a4 pc=0x83d216b
database/sql.OpenDB.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:791 +0x35 fp=0xa0577f0 sp=0xa0577e0 pc=0x83d0745
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa0577f4 sp=0xa0577f0 pc=0x80dde51
created by database/sql.OpenDB in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:791 +0x15c

eax    0x0
ebx    0x8e31a30
ecx    0x5d
edx    0x9f3ea70
edi    0x9f3ec30
esi    0x2
ebp    0x0
esp    0xffcf3cc0
eip    0x874c7c9
eflags 0x10216
cs     0x23
fs     0x0
gs     0x63
```

---

## Additional info(2023-11-10 16:32)

I tried to comment out the place where it crashes as below

```
diff --git a/src/accessor/resource/dbms.go b/src/accessor/resource/dbms.go
index 1138f57..1f993ff 100644
--- a/src/accessor/resource/dbms.go
+++ b/src/accessor/resource/dbms.go
@@ -93,14 +93,14 @@ func (db *DbmsDb) Begin() (accessor.DbmsTx, error) {
 }

 func (db *DbmsDb) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) error {
-       if _, err := db.Db.Exec(query, args...); err != nil {
-               // Code omission
-       }
+       // if _, err := db.Db.Exec(query, nil); err != nil {
+       //      // Code omission
+       // }
        return nil
 }
```

↑ db.Db's type is *sql.DB

App became to stop on calling `tx.Tx.Exec` with following error,   because exactly commented out code was should create this table.
At least, app is not crashing with SIGSEGV...

> no such table: my_table_name

---

## Additional info(2023-11-13 16:10)

If I use `SELECT TIME('now');` query instead of `create table ...` in Db.Exec arguments, app is not crashing.

Or if I use `CREATE TABLE xxxtest ();`,
then app prints `near ")": syntax error` message.
Again, app is not crashing and kindly providing an error.

---

## Reproducible example

### Code

#### go.mod

```
module tmp

go 1.21

require (
  github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.14.16
)
```

#### main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

const DB_FILENAME = "tmp.db"

func main() {
    db := createDatabase(DB_FILENAME)
    defer db.Close()

    res, err := db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL, "my_table_id" TEXT NOT NULL, "my_table_ja"    TEXT, "my_table_en" TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("mt_id" AUTOINCREMENT));`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("db.Exec() error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("db.Exec() result: %v\n", res)
}

func createDatabase(path string) *sql.DB {
    if pathExists(path) {
        removePath(path)
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", DB_FILENAME)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("sql.Open() error: %v\n", err)
    }

    return db
}

func pathExists(path string) bool {
    _, err := os.Stat(path)
    return !os.IsNotExist(err)
}

func removePath(path string) {
    if err := os.Remove(path); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("os.Remove() error: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

### Environment

```bash
> go env
GO111MODULE='on'
GOARCH='386'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/xxx/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/xxx/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS='-insecure'
GOHOSTARCH='386'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/media/sf_go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/media/sf_go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='direct'
GOROOT='/usr/local/go'
GOSUMDB='off'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.21.3'
GCCGO='/home/xxx/GCC-4.6.0/bin/gccgo'
GO386='sse2'
AR='ar'
CC='/home/xxx/GCC-4.6.0/bin/gcc'
CXX='/home/xxx/GCC-4.6.0/bin/g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/media/sf_go/src/tmp/go.mod'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m32 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build3046687627=/tmp/go-build'
```

### Error

```
> go build
> ./tmp
SIGSEGV: segmentation violation
PC=0x81ea110 m=0 sigcode=1
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x815de10, 0xa059a6c)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x61 fp=0xa059a58 sp=0xa059a40 pc=0x8055131
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3._Cfunc__sqlite3_step_row_internal(0x9e0f778, 0xa0143a8, 0xa0143b0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:378 +0x3b fp=0xa059a6c sp=0xa059a58 pc=0x8146a5b
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).execSync.func3(0xa06c200, 0xa0143a8, 0xa0143b0)
        /media/sf_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.16/sqlite3.go:2084 +0x62 fp=0xa059a84 sp=0xa059a6c pc=0x81589f2
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).execSync(0xa06c200, {0x83966e0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /media/sf_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.16/sqlite3.go:2084 +0x8d fp=0xa059ab4 sp=0xa059a84 pc=0x815878d
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteStmt).exec(0xa06c200, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0x83966e0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /media/sf_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.16/sqlite3.go:2046 +0x34b fp=0xa059b54 sp=0xa059ab4 pc=0x81585ab
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteConn).exec(0xa070060, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x83966e0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /media/sf_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.16/sqlite3.go:877 +0x24d fp=0xa059c0c sp=0xa059b54 pc=0x814fccd
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.(*SQLiteConn).ExecContext(0xa070060, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x83966e0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /media/sf_go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3@v1.14.16/sqlite3_go18.go:41 +0xe7 fp=0xa059c64 sp=0xa059c0c pc=0x8145f87
database/sql.ctxDriverExec({0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0xec75c010, 0xa070060}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x83966e0, 0x0, ...})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/ctxutil.go:31 +0x8f fp=0xa059cb8 sp=0xa059c64 pc=0x812aedf
database/sql.(*DB).execDC.func2()
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1675 +0x150 fp=0xa059d24 sp=0xa059cb8 pc=0x8131cb0
database/sql.withLock({0x828b29c, 0xa000060}, 0xa059df8)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:3502 +0x84 fp=0xa059d40 sp=0xa059d24 pc=0x8139294
database/sql.(*DB).execDC(0xa07e120, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, 0xa000060, 0xa059e7c, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1670 +0x24c fp=0xa059e44 sp=0xa059d40 pc=0x813173c
database/sql.(*DB).exec(0xa07e120, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1655 +0xdc fp=0xa059e88 sp=0xa059e44 pc=0x81314bc
database/sql.(*DB).ExecContext.func1(0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1634 +0x7c fp=0xa059ed0 sp=0xa059e88 pc=0x81312dc
database/sql.(*DB).retry(0xa07e120, 0xa059f18)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1538 +0x5f fp=0xa059ef8 sp=0xa059ed0 pc=0x81309cf
database/sql.(*DB).ExecContext(0xa07e120, {0x828b3d0, 0x83966e0}, {0x82643eb, 0x9c}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1633 +0xae fp=0xa059f48 sp=0xa059ef8 pc=0x813121e
database/sql.(*DB).Exec(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1647
main.main()
        /media/sf_go/src/tmp/main.go:17 +0xb3 fp=0xa059fa4 sp=0xa059f48 pc=0x815cb13
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267 +0x2dd fp=0xa059ff0 sp=0xa059fa4 pc=0x808a99d
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa059ff4 sp=0xa059ff0 pc=0x80b7821

goroutine 2 [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x8264920, 0x8383ce8, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa046fdc sp=0xa046fc8 pc=0x808ae4c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.forcegchelper()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:322 +0xd3 fp=0xa046ff0 sp=0xa046fdc pc=0x808ac93
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa046ff4 sp=0xa046ff0 pc=0x80b7821
created by runtime.init.5 in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:310 +0x23

goroutine 3 [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x8264920, 0x8383e90, 0xc, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa0477cc sp=0xa0477b8 pc=0x808ae4c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.bgsweep(0xa020500)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:280 +0x9b fp=0xa0477e8 sp=0xa0477cc pc=0x8075ddb
runtime.gcenable.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x27 fp=0xa0477f0 sp=0xa0477e8 pc=0x8067bd7
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa0477f4 sp=0xa0477f0 pc=0x80b7821
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x77

goroutine 4 [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x8264920, 0x8383f00, 0xd, 0x14, 0x2)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa047fb8 sp=0xa047fa4 pc=0x808ae4c
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x8383f00)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x60 fp=0xa047fcc sp=0xa047fb8 pc=0x8073130
runtime.bgscavenge(0xa020500)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x4b fp=0xa047fe8 sp=0xa047fcc pc=0x80737ab
runtime.gcenable.func2()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0x27 fp=0xa047ff0 sp=0xa047fe8 pc=0x8067b97
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa047ff4 sp=0xa047ff0 pc=0x80b7821
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0xb7

goroutine 5 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x8264898, 0x83967fc, 0x10, 0x14, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa048798 sp=0xa048784 pc=0x808ae4c
runtime.runfinq()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:193 +0xfc fp=0xa0487f0 sp=0xa048798 pc=0x8066d1c
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa0487f4 sp=0xa0487f0 pc=0x80b7821
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:163 +0x60

goroutine 6 [select]:
runtime.gopark(0x8264950, 0x0, 0x9, 0x18, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0x10c fp=0xa048ec4 sp=0xa048eb0 pc=0x808ae4c
runtime.selectgo(0xa048fcc, 0xa048fc4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:327 +0xaca fp=0xa048fa4 sp=0xa048ec4 pc=0x809b7ea
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xa07e120, {0x828b470, 0xa070030})
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1218 +0xab fp=0xa048fe0 sp=0xa048fa4 pc=0x812f1db
database/sql.OpenDB.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:791 +0x35 fp=0xa048ff0 sp=0xa048fe0 pc=0x812d7b5
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1363 +0x1 fp=0xa048ff4 sp=0xa048ff0 pc=0x80b7821
created by database/sql.OpenDB in goroutine 1
        /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:791 +0x15c

eax    0x0
ebx    0x8376d28
ecx    0x0
edx    0x1
edi    0x81ea0f0
esi    0x0
ebp    0x2
esp    0xffe05c60
eip    0x81ea110
eflags 0x10206
cs     0x23
fs     0x0
gs     0x63
```

---

## Additional info(2023-11-14 13:42)

If I create sqlite database not at golang code,
for example, I use [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/),
later in golang code I can use this database (SELECT, UPDATE and so on) without crash.

Seems like the problem exactly in `create table ...` query?...

---

## Additional info(2023-11-14 15:39)

### Behavior of app depending on different queries

```
(empty query)
db.Exec() result: {0xa4b0000 0xa4aa050}

CREATE TABLE 
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" 
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" (
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id"
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER)
SIGSEGV: segmentation violation
PC=0x81eb510 m=0 sigcode=1
signal arrived during cgo execution
```

Used code template for above logs:

```golang
    fmt.Print(`CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL);` + "\n")
    res, err = db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL);`)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("db.Exec() error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("db.Exec() result: %v\n\n", res)
```

ALSO!
If I register a `my_table` table with [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) in advance and run the app again,
the log will look like the following...

```
(empty query)
db.Exec() result: {0x9d28000 0x9d24040}

CREATE TABLE 
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" 
db.Exec() error: incomplete input
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" (
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id"
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER)
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL)
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>

CREATE TABLE "my_table" ("mt_id" INTEGER NOT NULL);
db.Exec() error: table "my_table" already exists
db.Exec() result: <nil>
```

---

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/1199).

---

## Additional info(2023-11-28 12:10)

As a temporary (or maybe not) solution,
I found [another library](https://pkg.go.dev/modernc.org/sqlite#section-readme) to use.

```
-       _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
+       _ "modernc.org/sqlite"
```

Comment: It is very seldom because of the Go runtime between versions, it could be a outdated module dependency among many things. Do share the relavant part of the code to help triage better

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], you don't want us to guess without any code, do you?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt , I added reproducible example.